# How to align icons and labels in an accordion using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and I am having a hard time the aligning some icons with labels when they are inside an accordion.

What I have achieved so far is supplied below, but I wanted the 3 icons on the left with equal spacing and the label on the right.

Also, I want to change the first icon (icon-chevron-down) to (icon-chevron-up) when the collapseOne is shown.

Here is some demo html:

```
    <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
        <div class="accordion-group">  
          <div class="accordion-heading">
          <table>  
            <tr>
              <td>
                 <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                 <label title="link ![enter image description here][2]1">link1</label>
              </td>
              <td>
               <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne"><i class="icon-chevron-down"></i></a>
              </td>
              <td>  
                <a href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
              </td>
             <tr>
            </table>
          </div>  
          <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px; ">  
            <div class="accordion-inner">  
              This is link 1
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-group">  
          <div class="accordion-heading">
          <table>  
            <tr>
              <td>
                 <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                 <label title="link 2">link2</label>
              </td>
              <td>
               <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne"><i class="icon-chevron-down"></i></a>
              </td>
              <td>  
                <a href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
              </td>
             <tr>
            </table>
          </div>  
          <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px; ">  
            <div class="accordion-inner">  
              This is link 2
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-group">  
          <div class="accordion-heading">
          <table>  
            <tr>
              <td>
                 <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                 <label title="link 3">link3</label>
              </td>
              <td>
               <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne"><i class="icon-chevron-down"></i></a>
              </td>
              <td>  
                <a href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="#"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
              </td>
             <tr>
            </table>
          </div>  
          <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px; ">  
            <div class="accordion-inner">  
              This is link 1
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The neat way to use will be like below : Jsfiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/PvwxN/2/)

```
<div class="accordion-heading">
 <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2"
href="#collapseOne"><i class="icon-home"></i> Heading <i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>   <i class="icon-edit"></i><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
</div>
```

To pull the icons right(as per your comment) you can do following :

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2"
href="#collapseOne"><i class="icon-home"></i> Heading<span class="pull-right"><i class=" icon-chevron-up"></i> <i class="icon-edit "></i><i class="icon-trash"></i></span></a>
```

As you have mentioned in your comment that, your headings are of variable length ,put the span out of the a tag , see below:

```
 <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2"
        href="#collapseOne"><i class="icon-home"></i> Headinghjhkjhjkhkjhkjhkjhkjhkjhkjhjkhkjhjkhkjhjkhjk</a>
  <span class="ico-pull pull-right"><i class=" icon-chevron-up"></i>  <i class="icon-edit "></i><i class="icon-trash"></i>
            </span>
    </div>
```

Than use the following css :

```
.accordion-heading > a {
width:8em;
white-space:nowrap;
overflow:hidden;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
.accordion-heading > span {
margin-right:20px;
margin-top:-28px;
}
```

Comment: okay. I will try to see. But i change the demo and came across another problem. Yes the text problem. If the text is continuous it doesn't respect the boundaries.

Comment: And also my a text (Heading in your case) is of variable width so to have a good look and feel I want all 3 icons on extreme right and if the text is more than certain length i will put something like Heading.... . Any idea regarding how it can be achieved

Comment: Yes you can use text-overflow:ellipsis for the heading so if the text is longer than expected the dots get visible .

Comment: in <div class="accordion-inner">yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</div> .It dosent respect the boundaries. Any ideas?

Comment: You will have to use text-overflow:ellipsis property , I have updated the jsfiddle  for it . Plz check